# when does Apache felix perform signature verification of a OSGI bundle .jar file?

Tags: digital-signature, apache-felix, osgi-bundle, apache-ace, signature-files

we have a command in apache felix to install an OSGi bundle i.e "felix:install Jar-file". My query is :Does this command also perform verification(before installing) of contents of jar-file against the signature with which it was signed earliar?
Or do we have any specific command in Apache felix to do the same.

If any above command does not perform verification then do i have to use
"jarsigner -verify jar-file" command provided by jarsigner tool in OSGi framework? if yes then how?

Or
do i have to write/embed some code/API in my own bundle code for verification which might run after installation and before resolving any the bundle's dependencies?if yes then what are those APIs provided by OSGi framework or some OSGi container implementaions(like Apache felix, Apache Ace, Equinox etc)?

Or does it require any configuration to set in OSGi bundle, specifically for signature verification?

please do share your some views.

Thanks

Comment: Good question ! I'm trying to find an answer to that very same problem too.